# What are pairwise non-intersecting lines in $\mathbb{P}^4$

Tags: terminology, projective-geometry

Given three lines, $L, M, N \in\mathbb{P}^4$, not in one hyperplane and not pairwise intersecting, I need to calculate

$$\dim(\langle L,M\rangle\cap N)$$.

I can however not find a definition for pairwise non-intersecting lines. How do I think about pairwise non-intersecting lines in $\mathbb{P}^4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. $L,M,N$ are pairwise non-intersecting if each pair doesn't intersect; that is, $L\cap M$, $M\cap N$, and $N\cap L$ are all empty.

This principle applies to many other "pairwise X" phrases as well.

Comment: So no line intersects any other line? What does the pairwise add? Why not just say they're not intersecting?

Comment: If we said they don't intersect, we would be saying that the triple intersection $L\cap M\cap N$ is empty - a much weaker condition.